# Invoke-RemoteScript : Server response: The specified script is invalid. SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions

while running below script I'm getting error saying in valid script, not sure what the issue is.

**Script**:

```
Clear-Host

Import-Module -Name SPE -Force

$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri https://dev.local/


Write-Host "SESSION" $session

Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-User -id admin }
```

**Error**

```
SESSION @{SessionId=4e5dd26c-9f8f-40d5-96af-512d881f0dbc; Username=admin; PersistentSession=False; UseDefaultCredentials=False; Credential=; SharedSecret=; Connection
=System.Object[]; Password=b}
Invoke-RemoteScript : Server response: The specified script is invalid.
At line:10 char:1
+ Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-User -id adm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (https://dev.local/:) [Write-Error], BadRequest
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Invoke-RemoteScript
```

**Sitecore Powershell version**

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682
PSEdition                      Desktop
SitecoreVersion                10.2.0.6766
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
SPEVersion                     6.4.0.16859
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1682
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**Windows Powershell**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                      
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                      
Script     1.0.0.0    ISE                                 {Get-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, New-IseSnippet}                                                                                                   
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}                                                                                    
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}                                                                                             
Script     6.4.0      SPE                                 {ConvertFrom-CliXml, ConvertTo-CliXml, Invoke-GenericMethod, Invoke-RemoteScript...}
```

Comment: What version of SPE installed in Sitecore? What version of the SPE Remoting module?

Comment: @MichaelWest updated the ticket.